# mocking a class used by a Gradle plugin when testing

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, mocking, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a Gradle plugin that interacts with an external HTTP API. This interaction is handled by a single class (let's call it `ApiClient`). I'm writing some high-level tests that use Gradle TestKit to simulate an entire build that uses the plugin, but I obviously don't want them to actually hit the API. Instead, I'd like to mock `ApiClient` and check that its methods have been called with the appropriate arguments, but I'm not sure how to actually inject the mocked version into the plugin. The plugin is instantiated somewhere deep within Gradle, and gets applied to the project being executed using its `void apply(Project project)` method, so there doesn't appear to be a way to inject a `MockApiClient` object.

Perhaps one way is to manually instantiate a `Project`, `apply()` the plugin to it (at which point, I *can* inject the mocked object because I have control over plugin instantiation), and then programmatically execute a task on the project, but how can I do that? I've read the Gradle API documentation and haven't seen an obvious way.

A worst-case solution will be to pass in a `debug` flag through the plugin extension configuration, which the plugin will then use to determine whether it should use the real `ApiClient` or a mock (which would print some easily grep-able messages to the STDOUT). This isn't ideal, though, since it's more fuzzy than checking the arguments actually passed to the `ApiClient` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could split your plugin into a few different plugins

- `my-plugin-common` - All the common stuff
- `my-plugin-real-services` - Adds the "real" services to the model (eg RealApiClient)
- `my-plugin-mock-services` - Adds "mock" services to the model (eg MockApiClient)
- `my-plugin` - Applies `my-plugin-real-services` and `my-plugin-common`
- `my-plugin-mock` - Applies `my-plugin-mock-services` and `my-plugin-common`

In the real world, people will only ever `apply: 'my-plugin'`

For testing you could `apply: 'my-plugin-mock'`

Comment: Nice. It's a good bit of overhead but that would probably work.

Comment: Also take a look at [plugin-contributed-services](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/dependency-injection-for-plugins.md#plugin-contributed-services) in the dependency-injection-for-plugins design docs. Never tried this myself

Comment: Unfortunately the link expired.